# Executing nested functions with a timer object

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing, timer, video-capture

I am trying to write a program which acquires an image from a webcam, averages over several of the vertical pixel rows, displays the result and then applies a Gaussian fit to locate the peak position with a high degree of accuracy. All of this is to be done in real time. I used a timer object to run the function (called datain) which triggers the camera and acquires the data. To iterate and update the data the function includes a while loop. My code worked perfectly until I added a command inside the while loop to call another function (called GaussianFit) which preformed the fit. When this function is added I receive an error which says the callback function in the timer does not have enough inputs.

"Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1' Not enough input arguments."

This seems odd since the data acquisition function provides all the inputs needed by the fitting function. My code is as follows:

```
function WaveAQ()
global webcamin


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create video object %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
dID = 2; vForm = 'MJPG_1280x720';

% Search for existing video objects to avoid creating multiple handles
vObj = imaqfind('DeviceID', dID, 'VideoFormat', vForm);

if isempty(vObj)
webcamin = videoinput('winvideo',dID,vForm);
else
webcamin = vObj{1};
end

% Configure # datasets to be averaged per measurement
set(webcamin,'FramesPerTrigger',1);
% Repeat until stopped
set(webcamin,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
% Set to grayscale
set(webcamin,'ReturnedColorSpace','grayscale');
% Allow webcam to be triggered by timer
triggerconfig(webcamin,'manual')

% % View the properties for the selected video source object.
% src_obj = getselectedsource(webcamin);
% get(src_obj)

% Prompt for dark reading
j = 1;
j = input('Would you like to take a dark reading? (y/n): ','s');
switch j
    case 'y'
        j = 1;
    case 'n'
        j = 2;
end

if j == 1
    prompt = input('Block input and enter any number to continue: ');
end
% We now define a function which will acquire data from the camera to be
% executed by the timer function
fig1 = figure(1);

function datain(~,event,input) 
persistent image
h = 1; % Initialize Loop
bg = 0;
avgroi = 0;


% Calibration and fitting constants
tol = 1;
calib_slope = .003126;
calib_offset = 781.8;
spect = (1:1280)*calib_slope + calib_offset;


while h == 1
    % Check if figure is open
    h = ishandle(fig1);
    trigger(input);

    % First run finds dark reading
    if j == 1
        bg = getdata(input,1,'uint8');
        j = 2;
    else 
    image = getdata(input,1,'uint8');
    image = image - bg; % Correct for background

    npxy = length(image(:,1));
    npxx = length(image(1,:));
    % Region of interest for spectral data
    dy_roi = 200;
    y_roi = npxy/2;
    % Region of interest for beam position
    dx_roi = npxx/2;
    x_roi = npxx/2;

    avgroi = sum(image((y_roi-dy_roi):(y_roi+dy_roi),:))/(2*dy_roi);
    avgroi = avgroi/256; % Normalize units
    avg_y = (sum(image(:,(x_roi-dx_roi+1):(x_roi+dx_roi))).'/(2*dx_roi)).';

    [cx,sx,Ipeak] = GaussianFit(avgroi,tol);
% cx = max(avgroi);
% sx = 2;
% Ipeak = max(avgroi);

    subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(spect,avgroi)
    title('Spectrogram')
    xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
    ylabel('Intensity (arb.)')
    legend(['\lambda_P_e_a_k = ',num2str(cx),'nm'])
    subplot(2,1,2)
    plot(1:length(avg_y),avg_y/256)
    title('Beam Profile in Y')
    xlabel('Pixel #')
    ylabel('Intensity (arb.)')
    end
end
end


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Define timer object to execute daq %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Set callback properies
timerfcn = @datain;
% Image acquisition rate
Raq = 5;

timer_exec = timer('TimerFcn',{timerfcn,webcamin},'period',1/Raq,'BusyMode','drop');% Maybe change busy mode to queue if regular acquisition interval needed.
% timer_exec2 = timer('TimerFcn',@GaussianFit,'period',1/Raq,'BusyMode','drop');
% Execute acquistion
start(webcamin);
preview(webcamin);
start(timer_exec);
% start(timer_exec2);

% Clean system
stop(timer_exec);
% stop(timer_exec2);
delete(timer);
stop(webcamin);
delete(webcamin);
clear functions;
end
```

Can anyone tell me why the timer needs more inputs when GaussianFit is called inside the loop?

Comment: The full error message would be more helpful. It is a lot of code o go through and it is easy to miss the error if not the full error message is there.

Comment: "Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1' 

Not enough input arguments."

That's it, the piece of code which causes the error is this:
    [cx,sx,Ipeak] = GaussianFit(avgroi,tol);
Which may be found just above the plotting block.

Comment: I think that the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) would be a lifesaver here. You should try it. Really simple and powerful. Further, you may want to check this `input` stuff. It is both a variable and a function in your code. You should make sure you do not shadow anything. The debugger should help with this as well.

Comment: A third thing to check may also be that you actually give the correct number of input arguments to `gaussianFit`. The message say that you get a "not enough input arguments". When you evaluate `TimerFcn`. It does not necessarily mean that the `TimerFcn` it self lacks input arguments. It is more likely the problem is with `gaussianFit`. Using the debugger you will actually be able to check what values `avgroi` and `tol` takes. Further, you may also want to make sure that `gaussianFit` actually wants 2 input arguments.

Comment: True, but as a variable input is only local to the function datain and it does not cause any problems. I'll look into the debugger but I know exactly where the error is; I just don't know how to fix it. If I remove the call to the GaussianFit function everything works smoothly. It seems as though using a timer callback function does not allow for a nested function within the callback unless I adjust the timer in some way. I actually wrote the GaussianFit function so its inputs are not an issue unless I need to tie its execution to the timer as well.

Comment: But you do not know why you get the error. Use the debugger `dbstop error;` to stop if error or set a breakpoint on the line. Then you will be able to either, hold the mouse over the variables or type them in the command window. If there is anything that may cause trouble or is unexpected it will show. This is the supreme way to treat a problem like this. The alternative is to do it like before the debugger era. That is, extensive logging. When none of these are present, debugging is really hard.